# How to set clipboard with Javascript outside a browser

Tags: javascript, clipboard

While automating processes in Illustrator with Javascript I came across the need to copy created svg-code to the clipboard to be able to paste it.

Is it possible to set the clipboard with javascript or is this a security violation?

Comment: Does this help? https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator-discussions/is-it-possible-to-copy-text-to-the-clipboard-in-illustrator-via-javascript/m-p/3424659#M154033

Comment: To a certain point but I want to know if there is a pure js way to set the clipboard

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard

Comment: `app.copy()` (for a selected text) is your friend. Or please provide a more detailed description of your workflow. How exactly do you get the svg-code? Is it an exported svg-file on your drive? Or it's a text inside some text frame on the page? Note, Illustrator describes its graphic with Postscritpt-like language, not SVG.

Comment: @YuriKhristich SVG-Code that is generated by script. Yes, it is possible to generate, save to file and import. No, app.copy() is not the solution.

Comment: Well, I just added the example how you can read contents of the file and put it into clipboard. Actually you don't have save the svg file. If you have its text you can copy it about the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var svg_file = File('d:\\abc.svg');
svg_file.open('r');
var contents = svg_file.read();
svg_file.close();

var doc = app.documents.add();

var temp_path = doc.pathItems.add(); // a workaround for the glitch
var frame = doc.textFrames.add();
frame.contents = contents;

// by some unknown reason Illustrator can't select a text frame 
// until you select something else first
// so here is the workaround
temp_path.selected = true;   // select the temp object
frame.selected = true;       // select the text frame
temp_path.selected = false;  // deselect the temp object

app.copy(); // <-- copy the selected text frame to clipboard

doc.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
```

It reads the file `d:\abc.svg`, creates a new document, puts the contents of the file on the page, copies the text to clipboard and closes the document.

Comment: Thank you for your effort but this solution is known to me. The question was if it is possible outside of browsers and illustrator set the clipboard to a certain content.

Comment: I see nowhere in your question the 'outside Illustrator' condition. If so, you don't need the `adobe-illustrator` tag in this case. It has nothing to do with Illustrator. Actually the condition is quite important. I would advice you to add to the question a more elaborate description what exactly you're doing. Probably you can run nodeJS script (which is Javascript and it has the access to the clipboard and files) or run bash/cmd command, or even Python, etc. It depends on details of your real workflow.